# How to present multiple greps as if they were in different columns?

Tags: awk, grep, format

Let's say.

I have one file with the name of the computer and some other information.

E.g.

- Computer1

There's another file with the ip address and some other information.

- 192.168.100.2

I have 2 greps for example:

- grep -i computer /etc/hosts
- grep -i ips /etc/hosts

They give me answers like

- Computer1
- 19.168.100.2

Well, I would like to get a file with headers and the information organized as this:

| Name | Ip |
| --- | --- |
| oser1313 | 19.168.100.1 |

I'm quite lost I have no idea how could I format this I usually copy-paste it on Excel but I don't want to do it anymore and since I have to do this on several computers from a server It would be great if I can format it.

Comment: Do you want a script that will generate the output as a markdown table?

Comment: I initialy thought that he wanted csv

Comment: Thank you for adding your efforts in your question(keep it up). Its always recommended to add samples of input and expected output in your question for better understanding of question, you are searching `computer` but you are getting output as `oser1313` which is this is specific part of that line NOT the exact line, so without you showing samples its difficult for us to understand your question completely, kindly do edit your question and let us know then.

Comment: Yup, sorry for any trouble. there is one file with the name of the computer in plain text. there is another file with the ip address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that your two files have the same number of lines and that line numbers match between one file and the other: if `oser1313` is line `n` in the output of `grep` from `/etc/hosts` then same for `19.168.100.1` in `/etc/hosts`.

So it turns pretty simple as bash script:

```
grep -i computer /etc/hosts > part1.dat

grep -i ips /etc/hosts > part2.dat 

echo "Name,IP" > out.dat

paste -d"," part1.dat part2.dat >> out.dat

rm part1.dat part2.dat
```

Or a oneliner, as suggested in comments:

```
printf "Name,IP\n$(grep -i computer /etc/hosts),$(grep -i ips /etc/hosts)\n" > out.dat
```

Comment: Why use the two extra files? You can do what you have with just `printf "Name,IP\n$(grep -i computer /etc/hosts),$(grep -i ips /etc/hosts)\n" > out.dat`.

Comment: Just because it is more readable for a beginner as it is here. Still, I edit to add your oneliner too ;)

Comment: Well sure, readability matters, but having two extra files just means they need to be cleaned up after. You can write something just as readable (by assigning the outputs of `grep` to two variables) without having the extra files to cleanup.

Comment: You're right. I expect this to be used in a script. So I added the rm line and that should be ok ;)

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm nitpicking now, but writing to a file, even if you remove it later, affects performance. It takes time to do I/O operations. If you use the shell's memory (i.e., storing intermediate values in variables) rather than writing to files, it will be a bit faster. That said, it might only be faster by a couple nanoseconds.

Comment: That said, you said it ;). When it comes to optimize for performance, that is a whole other question!

Comment: Thanks a lot this gave me the clue

Answer (score 3):

Just do something like this:

```
awk '
{ lc = tolower($0) }
lc ~ /computer/ { name = $0 }
lc ~ /ips/ { ip = $0 }
END {
    print "Name", "Ip"
    print name, ip
}
' /etc/hosts
```

The above is untested since you didn't provide a sample input file to test with and it's just mimicing what your grep commands do but there may be a better way to do it if we knew what your input looked like.